# R: Error in bind_rows_(x, .id), Argument 111 al combinar dataframes

Tags: r, binding

Estoy usando R versión 3.4.3. 
Tengo dos data.frames de diferente tamaño con algunas columnas comunes y otras no. Quiero combinar ambos data frames conservando las columnas diferentes de manera que aparezcan NAs en la parte del data frame donde dicha columna no estaba presente. Estoy usando la librería "dplyr" y la función "bind_rows":

```
    mydata_combine <- bind_rows(mydata,mydata2)
```

me sale el siguiente error:

```
   Error in bind_rows_(x, .id) : Argument 111 must be length 1309, not 2618
```

donde las columnas comunes de mis data frames son del mismo tamaño y tipo, y:

```
    > is.data.frame(mydata)
    [1] TRUE
    > is.data.frame(mydata2)
    [1] TRUE
    > ncol(mydata)
    [1] 127
    > ncol(mydata2)
    [1] 112
    > nrow(mydata)
    [1] 1309
    > nrow(mydata2)
    [1] 364
```

¿Podría alguien explicar por qué me sale este error? He usado esta función muchas veces con datos similares y nunca había tenido dicho error. Gracias!

Comment: La he redactado en inglés por que supuse que así podría llegar a más gente. No sabía que lo que pusiera en "Stackoverflow en español" estaría limitado a un público español.

Comment: Si .. este sitio es puramente en español para gente que prefiere este idioma o que directamente no sabe inglés. Para más info del sitio lee [tour]. Un saludo

Comment: Ele: ¿pero sabías que estabas en [es.so] o viniste desde [so] en inglés? Es pura curiosidad para saber cómo mejorar la interfaz de usuario

Comment: Vine desde Stack Overflow en español por ser la primera opción que salió en mi buscador, sin reparar en que estaba limitado a público español.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema se resuelve al usar la función [`rbind.fill()`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/plyr/versions/1.8.4/topics/rbind.fill)  del paquete "plyr":

```
mydata_combine <- rbind.fill(mydata,mydata2)
```